# SQLite set field to same value as generated id at insert

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

We have a requirement where some fields in a table need to have the same value as their ID. Unfortunately, we currently have to insert a new record and then, if needed, run another update to set the duplicate field (ID_2) value to equal the ID.

Here is the Android Sqlite code:

```
mDb.beginTransaction();  

// ... setting various fields here ...
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(NAME, obj.getName()); 

// now insert the record
long objId = mDb.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
obj.setId(objId);

// id2 needs to be the same as id:
obj.setId2(objId);

// but we need to persist it so we update it in a SECOND call
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("update " + TABLE_NAME);
query.append(" set " + ID_2 + "=" + objId);
query.append(" where " + ID + "=" + objId);
mDb.execSQL(query.toString());
mDb.setTransactionSuccessful();
```

As you can see, we are making a second call to set ID_2 to the same value of ID. Is there any way to set it at INSERT time and avoid the second call to the DB?

Update:

The ID is defined as follows:

```
ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ," +
```

Comment: AFAIK There is no way ... Even if you would get last Id fx by using `last_insert_rowid()` - `execSQL` doesn't support multiple statment in one execution ... off-topic comment: just get rid of ID_2 - as storeing it is redundant

Comment: ID_2 is not redundant. But there is no point opening that discussion here as it is out of scope of my Q.

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm used for autoincrementing columns is [documented](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html), so you could implement it manually in your code, and then use the new value for the INSERT.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite a ugly hack, but it may be possible :

```
with id_table as (
    select coalesce(max(seq), 0) + 1 as id_column 
    from sqlite_sequence 
    where name = 'MY_TABLE'
)
insert into MY_TABLE(ID_1, ID_2, SOME, OTHER, COLUMNS)
select id_column, id_column, 'SOME', 'OTHER', 'VALUES'
from id_table
```

It only works if the table ID is an `AUTOINCREMENT`, and is therefore managed via the documented [`sqlite_sequence`](https://sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#seqtab) table.

I also have no idea what happen in case of concurrent executions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an **AFTER INSERT TRIGGER** e.g.

Create your table (at least for this example) so that **ID_2** is defined as INTEGER DEFAULT -1 (0 or any negative value would be ok)

e.g. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS triggertest (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ,name TEXT ,id_2 INTEGER DEFAULT -1);`

Then you could use something like (perhaps when straight after the table is created, perhaps create it just before it's to be used and  drop it after done with it ) :-

```
CREATE TRIGGER triggertesting001 
    AFTER INSERT ON triggertest 
        BEGIN 
            UPDATE triggertest SET id_2 = `_id` 
            WHERE id_2 = -1; 
        END;
```

Drop using `DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS triggertesting001;`

Example usage (testing):-

```
INSERT INTO triggertest (name) VALUES('Fred');
INSERT INTO triggertest (name) VALUES('Bert');
INSERT INTO triggertest (name) VALUES('Harry');
```

### Result 1 :-

[image]

### Result 2 (trigger dropped inserts run again ):-

[image]

### Result 3 (created trigger) same as above.

### Result 4 (ran inserts for 3rd time) catch up i.e. 6 rows updated id_2 with _id.

[image]

I'd strongly suggest reading [SQL As Understood By SQLite - CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html)

---

## Alternative solution

An alternative approach could be to simply use :-

Before starting transaction, retrieve `mynextid` from table described below

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
contentValues.put(ID,mynextid);
contentvalues.put(ID_2,mynextid++);
contentValues.put(NAME, obj.getName());
```

Then at end of the transactions update/store the value of `mynextid` in a simple single column, single row table.

i.e. you are managing the id's (*not too dissimilar to how SQLite manages id's when 'AUTOINCREMENT' is specified*)

Comment: I will look into Triggers as I have never used them on Android. I like the concept :-)
Regarding the alternative solution: that would require an extra DB call which is what I want to avoid ;-) 
Thanks so much for the detailed answer! Well done.